Obtaining Incidence of death per X person years from KM survival curve?
Say I have interval censoring in my data and have derived KM curves for two groups with maximum follow up of 2 years. Death is the outcome of interest. For each group, how do I obtain number of death per X person years from the KM curves? Do I use the 1-survival probability at 2 years (i.e. CIF)? (e.g. (1-survival probability)/2*X where 2 is for the 2 years of follow up).
